# DRF - Reverse for 'widget-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Taking a second kick at HTML & Forms here

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

I have the following template called dashboard/widget_detail.html

{% load rest_framework %}

```
<html><body>

<h1>Profile - {{ widget.name }}</h1>

<form action="{% url 'widget-detail' pk=widget.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</body></html>
```

And the following view -

```
class WidgetDetail(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'dashboard/widget_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        widget= get_object_or_404(Password, pk=pk)
        serializer = WidgetSerializer(widget)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'widget': widget})

    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        widget= get_object_or_404(Widget, pk=pk)
        serializer = WidgetSerializer(widget)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'widget': widget})
        return redirect('widget-list')
```

These are being carried through the following urls -

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^widgets/$', views.WidgetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^widgets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.WidgetDetail.as_view()),
]
```

When trying to access the URL I get the following traceback -

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/enterpass/gui/views.py" in display_base
  39.                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  45.             using=using)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  115.                         template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in render_to_string
  221.             return t.render(context_instance)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  159.                 return template.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  211.                 return self._render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  578.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  495.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'widget-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I know it's failing because it's looking for a pk but I'm using this form for a post so therefore a PK is not going to exist.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^widgets/$', views.WidgetList.as_view(), name="widget-list"),
    url(r'^widgets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.WidgetDetail.as_view(), name="widget-detail"),
]
```

Comment: The stack trace you provided doesn't match the code samples you gave. Instead of the `WidgetDetail` it mentions `display_base`.